# angular unbind events when you leave a route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

One of routes in my application requires some special `keypress` event bindings, but none of the other routes do.

So, in that route's controller I'm binding the event like so:

```
angular.element( document.body ).bind('keydown keypress', function (event)
{
   //...
});
```

and I just noticed that when I navigate to that route, and then leave and go to a different route, those keyboard event bindings are still active.

How can I unbind the events whenever the route changes to a different controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unbind the event when scope gets destroyed.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    angular.element( document.body ).unbind('keydown keypress', handler);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ has references on how to unbind events.

The $destroy event gets fired whenever a scope gets destroyed in angular.

Comment: fyi the code should be `.unbind` but you've written `.bind`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function from jqLite when the scope is destroyed.